# How to remove duplicates out from a specific range but leave other data on the rights side and below?

Tags: excel, vba

I copy data from a list into another list in different sheet, whenever I copy data it copy the cells which are in the second list already. I need to delete any duplicates in the sheet number 2, though I always end up deleting everything including rows, gridlines and mostly the data on the right of columns. I only use cells from "A13", "B13" and "C13" down. There are data on the right, specifically formulas which are rather important. How can I only apply cleansing of duplicates on that range?

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics").Range("A13").CurrentRegion

   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
      LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      For i = 1 To LastRow

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Acrylics" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value

          End With
        End If

       Next i

    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    End With

End Sub
```

[image: This is how the list number 2 looks like before removing duplicates.]

[image: And this is how the code destroyes my list entirely.]

Comment: You'll need to define the range object for removeduplicates to only include the columns of interest.

Comment: Ok, I change this do define the range `Set rng = Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics").Range("A13:C1370")` ; duplicates are still in the list and  I also lost everything down the collumns, including gridlines and total rows.

Comment: Why does it erase gridlines?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, this code works for me. However, there is a problem with my gridlines as they are erased. I need to have the same format as it was in "A13" before I applied my code. I think of Scripting.Dictionary to store the format. Any idea? Better approach?

```
 Option Explicit
    Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng8 As Range 

    Set rng8 = Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics").Range("A13:C1370") 

     With Worksheets("Sheet1")
          LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

          For i = 1 To LastRow

            If .Cells(i, 6) = "Acrylics" Then
              With Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics")

                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value

                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
                   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8).Value

                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
                   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value

                rng8.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

              End With
            End If

           Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This sets your `rng` as the first three columns and also the `RemoveDuplicates` is an array of the first three columns.  If you only include column 1, it removes all duplicates that have the first column match only.  Also got rid of your nested `End With` statements to make it easier to follow.

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws1LR As Long
    Dim ws2LR As Long

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ws1LR = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(13, 1), ws1.Cells(ws1LR, 3))

    ws2LR = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To ws2LR

            If ws2.Cells(i, 6) = "Acrylics" Then
                ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                   ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value

                ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
                   ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value

                ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
                   ws2.Cells(i, 9).Value

            End If

        Next i

    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason it is not working. The duplicates are untouched, it only adds empty cells. I figure out how to do it in my code(I'll attach it soon) though it erase gridlines, apart from that it works fine.